# When I subclass a class in ByteBuddy, does my new dynamic class use the same class-level modifiers as the superclass?

Tags: byte-buddy

When I do `new ByteBuddy().subclass(something)`, and then eventually `make()` and `load()`, does the resulting dynamic class have the same type-level modifiers as the superclass?

For example, if I subclass a package-private class, will the newly-generated class also be package-private?

I ask because I am not seeing this.

If I call `toTypeDescription()` on the `DynamicType.Builder` and then `getVisibility()` on that `TypeDescription`, I see `Visibility.PUBLIC`.

**Update**: I see this only if I call it before I make a call to `modifiers()`, with *any* argument.  For example, if I call `toTypeDescription().getVisibility()` *after* I've called `modifiers(SyntheticState.SYNTHETIC)`, then the visibility reported is `PACKAGE_PRIVATE`.  If I call `toTypeDescription().getVisibility()` *before* I've called `modifiers(anything)`, then the visibility is `PUBLIC`.  I found this to be confusing and wanted to verify that it is intended behavior.

I understand that I can use `ByteBuddy.modifiers()` to set whatever modifiers I want.  But the defaults in this case (`PUBLIC`) were surprising to me, given that ByteBuddy often uses convention over configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, all generated classes are public, non-abstract. I would not expect any other behavior since you are generating a new class and this is the most common way to define one. If you retransform or redfine, the original modifiers remain in their original state.

If you call `.modifiers(SyntheticState.SYNTHETIC)`, you are replacing the default modifiers where package-private is the implicit visibility of the Java language. Set `Visibility.PUBLIC` to overcome this. If you only want to add a modifier without touching unrelated modifiers, you should use `.merge(SyntheticState.SYNTHETIC)`.

With `.toTypeDescription()` you are just creating a description of the currently instrumented type.

Comment: Aha; missed the `merge` method in the broad API surface; thanks.